# How to switch to previous window in another tabpage quickly?

Tags: vim

I really like the <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-I</kbd> to jump backward and forward.
If I open `fileA`, then use `:tabe fileB` to open another file in a new tabpage.
In the 2nd tabpage, I type <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> to jump back to the previous location.
Vim simply shows `fileA` in current window instead of switching to the 1st tabpage.
Now I have two tabpages display the same files. It is not I want.
I can use `:drop fileA`, but I need to provide full name. It's not good enough.
Is there some good way to switch between windows cross tabpages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the `switchbuf` setting:

```
set switchbuf=useopen,usetab
```

I *know* you know where to get more info on the possible values. ;-)

By the way, along with `set hidden`, this is the key to using buffers and windows and tabs efficiently in Vim.